# Why when I create a new model and try to retrieve its ID, it always returns 0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, model

When I create a new model and try to retrieve its **ID**, it always returns 0.

Why is that? I'm trying it after I add it to the corresponding set and context. As far as I know every time a new model is created, it recalls the DB and assigns a unique ID.

**StoreGeneratedPattern** value is set to **Identify** in the Model.edmx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will get number after `context.SaveChanges()`. Before it, there is no record in db for your new model object and it is not know id that will be generated on insert.

**Update**:

As example you have two tables: Books and Shelves. Any book can be placed in one of shelves and one shelve can contain many books. Typical one-to-many relationship.
EF generates to you two classes in model:
**Class Book**:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    ....//some other properites
    public virtual Shelve Shelve{get;set;} //navigation property to Shelve where this book is placed
}
```

**Class Shelve**:

```
public class Shelve
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set}
    ....//some other properties, as example address in library
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books{get;set;}
}
```

If you want to create a book and place it in existing shelve you should:

```
var book = new Book();
//initialize properties of book
var shelve = context.GetShelveById(shelveId); //get existing shelve from database by id
shelve.Books.Add(book);
context.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to create new shelve and add to it new book then you can use something like next sample:

```
var book = new Book();
//initialize properties of book
var shelve = new Shelve(); 
//initialize properties of Shelve
shelve.Books = new List<Book>();
shelve.Books.Add(book);
context.Add(shelve); //add shelve to context
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I see. I thought that could be the problem! :)

Okay, but let's say I have 3 tables in One-to-Many relationship. For example - Books, Students and Records. In Records I'm storing the Ids of a Book and a Student. 

I have to create two new records for a Book and Student and get their IDs in order to create a new Record.

When I try to call SaveChanges() when I create a new record for a Book and for a Student I get an error...

Comment: You have a navigation properties between Books, Students and Records, In Record in EF you should have public virtual properties: Book and Student, so you create book, create student, then create Record and assign Record.Book=book, Record.Student=student. And than SaveChanges()

Comment: Yes, I have navigation properties. 
Could you give me a simple example or link to already solved problem like mine? 
I would highly appreciate it! :)

Comment: I think I get the idea. 
Thank you for the spent time and explanations! :)